# How can I teleport small armor stands to my face and not my feet? 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a way to teleport a small armor stand to my head and not feet. But I’m not sure how to do so. Otherwise I wont be able to make guns that well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute a command at a player head](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/362482/how-to-execute-a-command-at-a-player-head)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to teleport the armorstand to you normally (ie, your feet as you are doing now), then teleporting it up by however much is needed, later in the same tick. Also make sure that you set the NoGravity:1b tag on the armorstand to stop it falling down.

ie:

Summon Command:

```
/summon armor_stand ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"ToTp",CustomNameVisible:0,NoGravity:1b,Small:1}
```

CmdBlk #1:

```
/tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=ToTp] @p[<identifier for player>]
```

CmdBlk #2:

```
/tp @e[type=armor_stand,name=ToTp] ~ ~0.5 ~
```

Where CmdBlk #1 chains into CmdBlk #2

Unfortunately this lags behind the player a little bit if you want to do it every tick, I haven't kept up to date on technical MC so I'm not sure if that's something you can get around with this method.